# How to do Accordions in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am a beginner for angular and I am trying to Accordions using below code but it's not working and showing error like **event.getElementsByClassName is not a function** can someone help me please where did I do wrong

### .html:

```
h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand($event)">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand($event)">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand($event)">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

### .css:

```
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### .ts:

```
export class HomePage {

  expand(event){

         var panel = event.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
         if (panel.style.display === "block") {
           panel.style.display = "none";
       } else {
             panel.style.display = "block";
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: It may be better for you to use ng-bootstrap's accordion (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) as it would seem to have all the functionality you require.

Comment: @rrd he is learning how Angular works, he doesn't want a library.

Comment: @trichetriche exactly, i want know what i did wrong in my code and how can i solve this

Comment: change `var panel = event.getElementsByClassName("accordion"); ` to `var panel = event.path[0].className;`  and try

Comment: thank for all your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have the good idea, you should stop using "old ways".

Angular is a framework with very powerful features. If you don't take advantage of them to their full extent, then you should not use it !

For instance look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zve4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion%2Faccordion.component.css) : although very minimal, it shows the power of Angular. No code in the component, and you already have an (non-animated) accordion !

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h2 class="title" (click)="opened = !opened">Title of the accordion</h2>
  <div class="content-container" [class.opened]="opened">
    <p class="content">Content of the accordion</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you to read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) so that you see everything Angular can do. I know it's long, but trust me, it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Ts function to:

```
 expand(event){
     if (event.style.display === "block") {
       event.style.display = "none";
   } else {
         event.style.display = "block";
    }  
}
```

And your HTML part should be:

```
    <h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand(panel1)">Section 1</button>
<div #panel1 class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand(panel2)">Section 2</button>
<div #panel2 class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" (click) = "expand(panel3)">Section 3</button>
<div #panel3 class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Here a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xstaru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**PS:** You can reach the same result in various different ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic list that you'd get from some API and then you want to render that in the accordion, you can create a CSS class(`visible` say) to apply a `display: block`

Then, create a property(`currentIndex`) in your Component Class. Whenever you click on a section, just set the `currentIndex` to the index of the section that was clicked. And based on the `currentIndex`, apply the `visible` CSS class via `[ngClass]`

Template:

```
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<div *ngFor="let section of sections; let i = index;">
  <button class="accordion" (click) = "expand(i)">{{section.name}}</button>
  <div class="panel"
    [ngClass]="{ 'visible' : currentIndex === i }">
    <p>{{section.content}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Class:

```
export class HomePage {
  currentIndex = -1;

  sections = [
    { name: 'Section 1', content: 'Content 1' },
    { name: 'Section 2', content: 'Content 2' },
    { name: 'Section 3', content: 'Content 3' },
    ...
  ];

  expand(index) {
    if(this.currentIndex === index) {
      this.currentIndex = null;
      return;
    }
    this.currentIndex = index;
  }

}
```

CSS:

```
...

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-eg?file=src/app/app.component.css) for your ref.

Comment: one small suggestion ,Based on current index section open if i want to close the current index section how can i do that?